# Display table not centering text vertically on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTMLcode:

CSS

```
.table{
    display:table;  
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="table">
<div class="table-cell">
    <a class="cta cta-1" href="#">Shop Now</a>
</div>
```

It centers the text vertically correctly on desktop, but I tried viewing it on my mobile (IPhone) and it doesn't work, the text is aligned to the top. Why would that be? You can see it here.
http://machinas.com/wip/stradviarius/startpage/

Comment: See also here: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/. They include what you're trying (which doesn't work for me, btw), but have other suggestions as well.

Comment: In Chrome on my desktop it also doesn't work.

Comment: it looks like on your site there insn't any of the CSS you include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your using fixed content that won't change you could do it using:

```
.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    margin-top:170px;
}
```

**OR** use `line-height` for the text (probably best):

```
.cta {
    line-height:339.328px;
}
```

339.328px is from your div heights.

Note: Your website doesn't vertical center the text on my Chromebook, so I assume it isn't working.

Comment: would rather not set fixed heights.